# Installation of tseries package fails

Tags: r

I'm tring to install tseries package on R. I get this output:

```
> install.packages('tseries') 
Warning in install.packages("tseries") : 
  argument 'lib' is missing: using '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' 
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session --- 
CRAN mirror 

1: Argentina (La Plata)      2: Argentina (Mendoza)    
3: Australia (Canberra)      4: Australia (Melbourne)  
5: Austria                  6: Belgium                
7: Brazil (PR)              8: Brazil (RJ)            
9: Brazil (SP 1)            10: Brazil (SP 2)          
11: Canada (BC)              12: Canada (NS)            
13: Canada (ON)              14: Canada (QC 1)          
15: Canada (QC 2)            16: Chile                  
17: China (Beijing 1)        18: China (Beijing 2)      
19: China (Hefei)            20: China (Hong Kong)      
21: China (Xiamen)          22: Colombia (Bogota)      
23: Colombia (Cali)          24: Denmark                
25: France (Toulouse)        26: France (Lyon 1)        
27: France (Lyon 2)          28: Germany (Berlin)      
29: Germany (Goettingen)    30: Germany (Muenchen)    
31: Germany (Wiesbaden)      32: Greece                
33: Indonesia                34: Iran                  
35: Ireland                  36: Italy (Milano)        
37: Italy (Padua)            38: Italy (Palermo)        
39: Japan (Hyogo)            40: Japan (Tsukuba)        
41: Korea                    42: Mexico (Mexico City)  
43: Mexico (Texcoco)        44: Netherlands (Amsterdam) 
45: Netherlands (Utrecht)    46: New Zealand            
47: Norway                  48: Philippines            
49: Poland (Gdansk)          50: Poland (Oswiecim)      
51: Poland (Wroclaw)        52: Russia                
53: Singapore                54: Slovakia 1            
55: Slovakia 2              56: South Africa          
5    7: Spain (Madrid)          58: Sweden                
59: Switzerland              60: Taiwan (Taichung)      
61: Taiwan (Taipei 1)        62: Taiwan (Taipei 2)      
63: Thailand                64: UK (Bristol)          
65: UK (London)              66: UK (St Andrews)        
67: USA (AZ)                68: USA (CA 1)            
69: USA (CA 2)              70: USA (IA)              
71: USA (MA)                72: USA (MI)              
73: USA (MO)                74: USA (OH)              
75: USA (OR)                76: USA (PA 1)            
77: USA (PA 2)              78: USA (TX 1)            
79: USA (TX 2)              80: USA (WA 1)            
81: USA (WA 2)              

Selection: 80 
Warning: dependency ‘quadprog’ is not available 
trying URL 'http://cran.fhcrc.org/src/contrib/tseries_0.10-26.tar.gz' 
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 163770 bytes (159 Kb) 
opened URL 
================================================== 
downloaded 159 Kb 

ERROR: dependencies ‘quadprog’ are not available for package ‘tseries’ 
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/tseries’ 

The downloaded packages are in 
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp4BUi9T/downloaded_packages’ 
Warning message: 
In install.packages("tseries") : 
  installation of package 'tseries' had non-zero exit status
```

How can I install this package?

Comment: R --version
R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31)

Comment: Well that is your problem. Update your R to the latest version; quadprog depends on >= 2.12.0. You can try installing from source, but that might be more hassle than updating R. See my Answer for more.

Answer (score 6):

**tseries** depends on the **quadprog** package. You don't have that package installed, and it was not available on the CRAN mirror you used for the version of R you are using (unstated). Hence **tseries** can not be installed.

You need to install **quadprog** for your version of R. It may not be available if you are a few versions behind the current; **quadprog depends on R >= 2.12.0**.

[By the way, these things are R *packages*, not *libraries*.]

Comment: ubuntu server doesnt have this version on the repositories

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu you can compile from sources; these are available from CRAN. You'll need to find a version that will work with an R that  old. Then you'll need to install the OS tools/compilers etc you need to build from sources. At this point I can't help further; I am not familiar with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and then solved it in the following way.

Using the Terminal in Ubuntu, I typed the following commands:

```
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/quadprog_1.5-4.tar.gz
sudo R CMD INSTALL quadprog_1.5-4.tar.gz
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/tseries_0.10-30.tar.gz
sudo R CMD INSTALL tseries_0.10-30.tar.gz
```

With this done, I was then able to start an R session, load the tseries package, and use its functions with success.

You may wish to install different versions of the quadprog and tseries packages. If that's the case, please alter the above url links accordingly.